# getting the last day of the month in a timestamp format

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column with a timestamp from which I'm extracting the last day of each month using `last_day()`, but the function gives me only the date part of the timestamp, and when I use `to_timestamp()` within it, it zeroes out the time values which in this case are very relevant because that determines which values comes has higher precedence.

Is there a way to get the last day of the month of a timestamp in a timestamp format without losing the time values?

Currently, I have a regular SQL query using SparkSQL as follows:

```
 spark.sql("SELECT DISTINCT max(col1) AS col1, \
                  col2, col3,\
                  max(col4) AS col4,\
                  last_day(col5_date) as col5_date\
                  FROM table \
                  GROUP BY col1,  col2,\
                  col3, col4, col5").registerTempTable("table1")
```

The above gives me the following result:

| Col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | 2022-11-30 |

And when I tried the `to_timestamp` function on the `Last_day()` function this is what I get:

| Col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | 2022-12-31 00:00:00 |

However, the data does have the time data in it, like this: `2022-10-28 12:32:...`. Is there any way I can preserve the time in the timestamp when retrieving the last day of the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Method-1:`**

Try with `make_timestamp()` function and pass `year+month+date+hours+minutes+secs` to the function.

**Explanation:**

```
make_timestamp(year(last_day(ts)), -- get year from last_day()
month(last_day(ts)),-- get month from last_day()
day(last_day(ts)),-- get day from last_day()
hour(ts),-- get hour from timestamp column
minute(ts),-- get minute from timestamp column
second(ts))-- get second from timestamp column
```

**`Example:`**

```
with cte as (
  select current_timestamp() as ts
) select *,make_timestamp(year(last_day(ts)),month(last_day(ts)),day(last_day(ts)),hour(ts),minute(ts),second(ts)) as col5 from cte
#ts                             col5
#2023-05-19T22:12:26.027+0000   2023-05-31T22:12:26.000+0000
```

---

**`Method-2:`**

With using combination of `to_timestamp + last_day + date_format` functions we are going to get the HH:mm:ss from the timestamp and add it to `last_day()` function.

```
with cte as (
  select current_timestamp() as ts
) select *,to_timestamp(concat_ws(" ",last_day(ts),date_format(ts,"HH:mm:ss"))) as col5 from cte
#ts                             col5
#2023-05-19T22:18:08.710+0000   2023-05-31T22:18:08.000+0000
```

Comment: thank for giving the possible alternatives. I do a question though, with this approach (either of them) it implies 2 different queries, correct, the initial one I posted (because the values are dependent on the date and, the "With" query with it, or am I mistaken. - Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, the first method worked for my use case, thank you very much!